# "I spilled water on the table and [the] floor"

Tags: conjunctions, definite-articles, parallelism, zero-article

Compare the sentences:

> - I spilled water on the floor.
> - I spilled water on the table and floor.
> - I spilled water on the table and the chair.

1. Is the missing *the* before *floor* in the second sentence correct?
2. If so, is the *the* before *chair* in the third sentence optional?
3. What is the general rule applicable in such cases? Is it rule related to the conjunction, or the nature of the noun like *floor*, or both?

Comment: You can use or not use the second "the".  The implication is slightly different, but only slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec073.html) Chapter 5, Section 73 (sorry, subscription required) says that, with a series of coordinate nouns, an article may appear before each noun, but is not necessary.

So, for question 1:

> Is the missing *the* before *floor* in *I spilled water on the table and floor* correct?

Yes

And 2:

> Is the *the* before *chair* in *I spilled water on the table and the chair* optional?

Yes

In these cases, it is a matter of preference and, perhaps, emphasis.

Comment: Ta. Not enough reputation to accept answer/upvote. Given a table the floor is identified from the context, unlike the chair - does that play part in using or not using the article or the type of article.

Comment: @enjayes as the question asker, you can select the gray checkmark next to an answer to mark it accepted. That doesn't require any reputation.  You could make an argument that including an article before each coordinate noun adds more emphasis to where the spill landed (vs. that the spill occurred). Your question about *floor* vs. *table* is less of a concern here. It sounds like you're trying to apply the logic of when to use a definite vs. indefinite article, but that's not the case here. "a" would be odd in either case.